# Pandas and Python: Saving result of .sum() outside of for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe in this structure (mine has several thousand columns/rows):

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [0, 2, 2],
                        'b': [2, 1, 2],
                        'c': [0, 2, 2]})
```

I'm summing all the values using `.sum()` within a for loop:

```
sumtest = testdf.sum()
```

I want to be able to add these values to something outside the for loop. Each time the loop occurs, values should be added on to something (a dictionary?) outside the loop. The final goal is to export all the added values once the for looping has finished.

When I `print(sumtest)`, I get:

```
a    4
b    5
c    4
```

But I don't want to just print the values each time the for loop occurs, I want them to add together each time the for loop runs (so that at the end I can add them all to a .csv with only one entry for each `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.) New values are generated each time the for loop runs, so the second loop could produce `a 7`, `b 8`, `c 10`.

As I said, I want to add these values to something outside the for loop, so each time it goes through again more values are added on. I tried using `enumerate` to get each value out to add it to a dictionary, but that doesn't give me my `a`, `b`, `c`, it only gives the values.

It's not important how it's done, but I need a way to 1) autogenerate all the column names (`a`, `b`, `c`, etc), 2) associate those with their number, with the sum increasing each time the for loop runs, 3) save these to a .csv once the for loops are finished.

I tried using `sumtest.to_csv('sumtest.csv', mode='a')` at the end of each for loop, but it gives me a file with the values repeated instead of added:

```
a    4
b    5
c    4
a    7
b    8
c    10
...  ...
```

Instead, the final output should be like (commas not necessary, I'm just thinking for a .csv):

```
a, 11
b, 13
c, 14
```

Comment: `df.cumsum()`???

Comment: It's a little unclear what you mean by "add these values to something outside the for loop".  Can you provide your expected output, and code for what that "something" would look like?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by 'sum increasing each time the for loop runs'. Can you show the final output that you want to write to csv?

Comment: @andrew_reece Added, I hope that helps!

Comment: I'm still a little confused.  Are you saying that you have a for loop, and for each iteration you want to add the column-wise sums of `testdf` to a running sum?  So the same values are added to separate running totals for `a`, `b`, and `c` for every iteration?  If so, why not just multiply the column sums times the iteration length and store that?  Why do you need to perform `sum()` in each loop?  And how do you get to `8, 5, 8` for your final output?  Why is `b` not increased?  Try to provide as close as possible to a [mcve].  As is, there's not enough information to give a precise answer.

Comment: @andrew_reece I should have been more clear, each time the for loop runs new values are generated for the columns `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. I'm having difficulty coming up with a minimal example, basically my code runs through chunks of a massive df and sums the columns for each chunk in a particular way. The df is so big that I have to sum each chunk individually, but I'm not sure how to represent that in my question in a minimal way.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying.  See my answer, I think I understand what you're going for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can just `add()` each `sum(axis=0)` to a running master data frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)

# starting empty dataframe
master = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((1, 3)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

n = 10
for _ in range(n):
    # initialize new data for a, b, c on each loop
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(3, 3)), columns=['a','b','c'])
    # compute column sums, add to master
    master = master.add(df.sum(axis=0))

# transpose to get column names as row indices, per OP specs
master.T
      0
a  52.0
b  67.0
c  74.0

master.T.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a loop that calls various parts of the data frame and produces`sumtest` each time it runs?

If so, within each loop, you can create a dict out of the sumtest, then use Counter on that dict, and then add it to a dict defined outside of the loop, to which the loop continually adds.

Here's how it works inside what you've posted above, if I just duplicate your dataframe into a second dictionary, and add those two together:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
testdf = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [0, 2, 2],
                        'b': [2, 1, 2],
                        'c': [0, 2, 2]})

sumtest = testdf.sum()
sumtest2 = testdf.sum()
st = Counter(dict(sumtest))
st2 = Counter(dict(sumtest2))
stc = st + st2
print(stc)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'b': 10, 'a': 8, 'c': 8})
```

The difference here between what I'm doing and what you'd do, is that inside whatever loop you're running (as a function, I'm assuming?), you'd have your overall dictionary input as a variable to the function, and then you'd add the two Counters inside the loop, and then have the function return the sum of those two dictionaries as your new overall dictionary.

Without more of a sense of the language of the for loop, it's hard to specify, but this works in itself, and modifying it as I've described will get it to work inside any for loop.